# Directive result does not have the same when using method directly

Tags: angular, angular8

On an Angular 8 component HTML I am checking authorisation through an `authorize` directive:

```
 <button (click)="createPost()" *authorize="'Create'; id: postId">Add post > Directive</button>
```

I get inconsistent behaviour ... I know the User is authorized so the button should always be visible.

1. If I click on a link to go to the page the button is visible;
2. If I navigate to the page from another component using `this.router.navigate` the button is sometimes visible other times is not visible.

**NOTE:** The directive simply calls an Authorization service.

So I tried to inject the Authorization service in the component directly and not use the directive:

```
<button (click)="createPost()" *ngIf="authorize('Create', postId)">Add post > Method in Component</button>
```

In this case it works fine ... So I think my directive has some kind of problem:

**AuthorizeDirective**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[authorize]'
})

export class AuthorizeDirective implements OnInit {

  requirement: Requirement;
  id: number;

  @Input() set authorize(requirement: string) {
    this.requirement = Requirement[requirement];
  }

  @Input() set authorizeId(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  constructor(private template: TemplateRef<any>, private container: ViewContainerRef, private authorizationService: AuthorizationService) { }

  ngOnInit() { 

    this.authorizationService.authorize(this.requirement, this.id).pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged()
    ).subscribe(x => {
      x ? this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template) : this.container.clear();
    });

  }

}
```

**AuthorizationService**

```
@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root' 
})

export class AuthorizationService {

  private notifier: Subscription;

  private permissions$: BehaviorSubject<PermissionModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<PermissionModel[]>([]);

  constructor(private noteService: NoteService, private permissionService: PermissionService, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { 

    this.getPermissions();

    // Update permissions if user permissions were modified
    this.notifier = this.noteService.get().subscribe((note: Note) => { 

      if (note.code == NoteCode.PermissionsModified) {
        this.getPermissions();
      }

    });

  }

  private getPermissions() {

    let userId: this.authenticationService.getUserId();

    this.permissionService.get(userId).subscribe((permissions: PermissionModel[]>) => { 
      this.permissions$.next(permissions) 
    });

  }

  authorize(requirement: Requirement, id: number) : Observable<boolean> {

    switch(requirement) { 

      case Requirement.Create:

        return this.permissions$.asObservable().pipe(
          map(permissions => permissions.find(x => x.id === id)),
          map(permission => permission ? ['Admin', 'Client'].some(x => x === permission.name) : false    
          })
        );

    } 

    return of(false);

  }
```

**Component**

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  postId: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private authorizationService: AuthorizationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(parameters => {
      this.postId = parameters.has('postId') ? +parameters.get('postId') : undefined;
    })

  }

  public createPost() {
    // Create Post
  }

  // Method used in second example that uses `ngIf` and not the directive
  public authorize(requirement: string, id: number) : Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authorizationService.authorize(Requirement[requirement], id);
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong in my directive?

Comment: rather than putting your directive logic in `ngOnInit` try to put it in `ngOnChange`.

Comment: I just tried but I get the same problem